# Kubuntu 18.04 always start with Arabic keyboard layout

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, kubuntu, keyboard-layout

In my [kubuntu](/questions/tagged/kubuntu) [18.04](/questions/tagged/18.04) I have two keyboard layouts, English(US) and Arabic. When I tend to start my computer and after login, Arabic layout is enabled by default. I just want the English(US) to be enabled by default not Arabic. I could not able to find any settings option that allows to set a default keyboard layout. I have tried to change layouts order in `settings -> Keyboard Hardware and Layout -> Layouts` but it leads to loss custom layout shortcuts.:

[image]

## Update

It seems that Kubuntu after user login, starts using latest keyboard layout the user used it in the previous session. So when I shut down my computer with Arabic layout, it logins again with Arabic and vice versa for English.

**However, still there is no any option to overcome this situation. i.e an option to stick the starting layout after login to a specific layout regarding less what was used in the previous session.**

Comment: I think it remembers the last used layout for a good reason. Most users would find anything else as unexpected behavior.